# How to Add Entity Framework with PostGresql in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: asp.net, database, postgresql

I have database in Postgresql and I to add Entity Framework in my ASP.NET Web Project.

Could anyone please let me know the good way.

Much Appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Npgsql`, see the reference [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html). If you have specific question about `Npgsql` usage with EF, edit this question to include problem details and what you're tried to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I need to use with LINQ not SQL query.